# how to pass void function pointer as parameter

Tags: c++, dll, callback, function-pointers, stdcall

I need to use the function `SetEventCallback` in 3rd party dll.

```
void  __stdcall SetEventCallback(void __stdcall callbackFunc(int val))
```

This function registers `callbackFunc` as callback function of some registered events. If an event occurs, `callbackFunc` is called and you could know which event is occured through parameter `val`.

**I want to know how to use the function `SetEventCallback`**.

---

I tried using it as follows.

1. Import function in dll

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void  __stdcall SetEventCallback(void __stdcall callbackFunc(int val));
```

2. Define callback function in my application

```
void __stdcall callbackInApp(int val) {

    if(val == 0) {
        // Do something with val
    }
    else {
        // Do something with val
    }  
}
```

3. Call function `SetEventCallback` by passing the function pointer as parameter

```
int main(void) {
 
    SetEventCallback(callbackInApp);
}
```

---

Compilation is success but `callbackInApp` is never called.
Please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: Hopefully the 3rd party DLL came with some documentation. Everything you need to know should be described in it. If it isn't, then you are out of luck. At least you should tell us what that 3rd party DLL is...

Comment: Looking at the code shown, you're passing your callback correctly. The issue is elsewhere.

Comment: How do you know it's never called?

Comment: @CristiFati I did debugging line by line and the callback function was never called. I think the registering was not worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no documents for this 3rd party DLL. 
Since this is private service module, I can't even expain what this module is.
I asked question here to get answers fast, but I think I can't give you full information about the problem.
I think I should contact to developer even if it takes several days to get answer.
Thanks to all of you.